# Ошибка при объявлении двух глобальных переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('!m_change'):     
    global DIR
    global MODE
    if (DIR == 'arts/normal' and MODE == 'Обычный.'):
        DIR = 'arts/hentai'
        MODE = 'Хентай.'
    elif (DIR == 'arts/hentai' and MODE == 'Хентай.'):
        DIR = 'arts/normal'
        MODE = 'Обычный.'
    print('Запрос на переключение режима. Текущий режим: ' + MODE)
    await message.channel.send('Режим переключён.')
    return
```

При объявлении переменных `DIR` и `MODE` глобальными, в консоли появляется ошибка:

> name 'MODE' is used prior to global declaration

, но ошибка не появляется, если объявляется только одна переменная, DIR или MODE.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поместите объявление

```
global DIR
global MODE
```

перед вызовом функции

Comment: Поместил перед оператором if. Не помогло.

Comment: @BlitGaming перед вызовом функции, а не перед оператором if...

Comment: Окей буду знать.

Comment: Оказалось проблема была в том что я выносил каждую переменную на каждую строчку, а не в том где была эта строка. Просто я писал этого бота в Sublime Text, а там не подсвечиваются ошибки, как в Pycharm'е